# Is it possible to have either or whereFields for Firestore query?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to have a query like

```
db.collection("Bookings")
    .whereField("servicer", isEqualTo: userID || "customer", isEqualTo: userID)
```

Instead of having two different reads it will just have one, and it gets all the documents that `servicer == userID` and `customer == userID`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with a single query - there is no logical OR operation that works across multiple fields in a document.  You will need to have two queries, one for "servicer", and another for "customer", then merge the results of those queries on the client.

Comment: Could I possibly use a Firestore index? I've been reading about it but couldn't seem to find an example that suits mine.

Comment: No, there is nothing that will help compress two queries on two different fields into one.  This is just the way Firestore works.  You can only combine fields using a logical AND, not logical OR.